# Cell Indexing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have read the docs for accessing a cell array in

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html

It seems fairly straightforward; however, I appear to be lost as to access the `1X1 struct` below.

I have an object (`first_elem`) which has class `cell`.

I wish to see the contents of the struct as I have just loaded in a MATLAB dataset for analysis.

```
>> first_elem

first_elem = 

    [1x1 struct]

>> class(first_elem)

ans =

cell

>> first_elem(1)

ans = 

    [1x1 struct]

>> class(first_elem(1))

ans =

cell
```

However, when I index the for the first element with `(1)`, I get back another `cell` object instead of the `1x1 struct` shown in `[1x1 struct]`.

Am I missing something here?

Additional Context:

The initial file I loaded contained multiple datasets and looked like

```
>> display(train_small)

train_small = 

    train: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
```

after loading.

I attempted to look at the contents of the first dataset with

```
first_elem = train_small.train(1)
```

Comment: It doesn't usually make sense to put structs inside cells. If all the structs have the same field names, use a struct array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first_elem(1)` returns a cell containing the first element only

`first_elem{1}` returns the first element